# What does means such offsets [rax+r14d-15] [rdi*1+r14]

Tags: assembly, x86-64, addressing-mode

Became to learn asm and can not understand what mean means those offsets,

in default [EBX+000008c]  or same it`s clear but not when register plus or minus other register

put some examples please

Comment: You can subtract *registers* in x86-64 addressing modes, but yes you can add signed constant displacements.  The machine code uses 2's complement to encode the signed integer, of course.  (ARM has `-reg` but x86 unfortunately doesn't).

Comment: @rcgldr: yes, oops.  I wish I could edit comments >.<

Comment: You could copy / repost the comment, then delete the old one. I deleted my prior comment, and will delete this one later.